# using on function instead of live in jquery 1.10

Tags: jquery

i write a code.My element currently doesn't exist. code is

```
jQuery('a.feedSearchClear').on('click',function(evt){
  console.log('coming here');
  var intId = window.setInterval(function(){
   if(jQuery('#feedSortDropDownElement').parent().find('ul').find('a').length > 0) 
{     window.clearInterval(intId);
      jQuery(".feedSortMenuContainer").prepend(menu_html);
     reRenderMenu();

}
},1000);

});
```

when i click on that button when it appears. it is not showing console log means method is not called. can anyone explain why ??

Comment: Read this http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is already answered by the official documentation

Answer (score 1):

What's happening is that you are applying bindings directly to the selected elements:

```
$("a.example").on("click", do_stuff);
```

In the above, you are saying, "jQuery, find all the `a` tags on the page with a class of `example`, and apply this `click` binding".  The problem in your case is that you don't have the elements on the page yet.

You can fix this by putting the binding on an **ancestor node** (any node higher up the hierarchy), and letting it handle the events for you.  The simplest way is to use the `body` tag, like so:

```
$("body").on("click", "a.example", do_stuff);
```

Now, you're saying, "jQuery, any time an `a` tag with the class of `example` is clicked *within the `body` tag*, do this stuff".

You're basically telling the body tag to listen for events *on behalf of the child node*, even though that child node doesn't exist at the time.

Comment: Ahh, correct! I'll edit my post accordingly!

Answer (score 0):

Delegate event to *parent* of the dynamically added element or delegate to `document`

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.feedSearchClear',function(evt){
  console.log('coming here');
  var intId = window.setInterval(function(){
    if(jQuery('#feedSortDropDownElement').parent().find('ul').find('a').length > 0) 
    {  
       window.clearInterval(intId);
      jQuery(".feedSortMenuContainer").prepend(menu_html);
       reRenderMenu();

     }
   ,1000);    
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).